# Failure to restore nuget packages from organisation feed

Tags: azure-devops

I am using the following step in my `azure-pipelines.yml` file:

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: dotnet restore
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'TEC-Get'
    includeNuGetOrg: true
```

Unfortunately this fails with the following error on running the pipeline:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.201\NuGet.targets(131,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden - User 'b55d7ea1-921b-49df-87fe-761c8c8988d0' lacks permission to complete this action. You need to have 'ReadPackages'. (DevOps Activity ID: 59D1A1DF-6300-427C-9BAA-16A2FA5EF74E)). [D:\a\1\s\Common\Common.csproj]
           GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata/index.json
         NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/TEC007/_packaging/TEC-Get/nuget/v3/index.json.
```

From the error it is clear I need to grant permission to a user, but I don't know how I can tell which one it is within my organisation.

Can anyone help with this please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Azure DevOps pipeline, it restore the package via service account instead of personal account. Check this doc: [Package permissions in Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/feed-permissions?view=azure-devops#package-permissions-in-azure-pipelines)

> To use packages from a feed in Azure Pipelines, the appropriate build identity must have permission to your feed. By default, the **Project Collection Build Service** is a Contributor. If you've changed your builds to run at [project scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#job-authorization-scope), you'll need to add the project-level build identity as a Reader or Contributor, as desired. The project-level build identity is named as follows: `[Project name] Build Service ([Organization name])`

We could also do this via click the button `Allow project-scoped builds`, check the pic below.

[image]